# Common default arguments in class methods

Tags: python, function, class, arguments, default-arguments

I created a class where 3 arguments are always the same by default:

```
    class Test:
        def f1(a, b, verbose=True, delim='\t', lvl=0):
            ...
        def f2(c, verbose=True, delim='\t', lvl=0):
            ...
        def f3(d, e, f, verbose=True, delim='\t', lvl=0):
            ...
```

Sometimes of course, I need `f2` with `lvl=1` for instance, so I need some flexibility, while the default should always be `lvl=0` for each function I create.
I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to do it than what I just wrote.

Comment: Your code is okay. If there's some common code in each of those methods which relies on these arguments, you can move it out in another private method, e.g. `def _f(verbose=True, delim='\t', lvl=0)`, so you can change your function declaration to `def f1(a, b, **kwargs)` and call this method in function body `_f(**kwargs)`.

Comment: Seems fine, most cleverer solutions are likely less readable. Also in IDEs it's nice to have explicitly defined args, to get clear hints when calling. Don't forget `self` arg.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please provide an example of how _f would be defined and interacting with other functions?

Comment: your functions should have `self` as the first parameter or be decorated with `@staticmethod`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd leave it as is. You could store the defaults outside of the class, for example:

```
class TestDefaults:
    verbose = True
    ...
```

and then use `verbose=TestDefaults.verbose`.