# Common default argument in Python class，how can I solve it?

Tags: python

I created a class where 3 arguments are always the same by default:

```
 class Test:
        def f1(a, b, verbose=True, delim='\t', lvl=0):
            ...
        def f2(c, verbose=True, delim='\t', lvl=0):
            ...
        def f3(d, e, f, verbose=True, delim='\t', lvl=0):
            ...
        ...
```

Sometimes of course, I need f2 with lvl=1 for instance, so I need some flexibility, while the default should always be lvl=0 for each function I create. I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to do it than what I just wrote.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72629634/common-default-argument-in-python-class this is exactly the same question but asked by a different user

Comment: So, Yves, maybe not create more than one account? What do you say?

Answer (score 1):

At least the names `verbose` and `delim` suggest that these are like generic *options*. Instead of defining these as parameters, you could set them as attributes of your instance.

Side issue: as these functions are methods, it would be appropriate to have a `self` parameter.

For example:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, verbose=True, delim='\t', lvl=0):
        self.verbose = verbose
        self.delim = delim
        self.lvl = lvl

    def f1(self, a, b):
        # ...
        s = self.delim.join(a)
        # ...

    def f2(self, c):
        # ...
    
    def f3(self, d, e, f):
        # ...

# Example use
test = Test(verbose=True)
test.f1(["a", "x"], "b")
test.verbose = False
test.delim = "!"
test.f2("c")
```

Comment: you forgot self in each functions

Comment: Updated, @Nitish, the asker had forgotten them.